# Java ME Nokia Eclipse/Netbeans not show exception's source

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, java-me

I tried both Eclipse and Netbeans with Nokia SDK 1.0 (I need exactly 1.0 for old devices), but there are serious hardship when I work with it - when I get an exception, it only shows the exception's type, but not the place in code where it goes from.

Comment: What exceptions do you get?

Comment: @AmeerMoaaviah with any type, also, I fount some workaround - wrapped the most suspicious methods with try{ .... } catch(RuntimeException e) {
 System.out.println("catch exception");
 e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Try using Sony Erricsson SDK 2.5. You will get the exact line where you are getting issues.